# How to make my repository distinguish backend/frontend

Tags: php, symfony, silex

I'm buliding a webshop with an administration area to manage products. In the admin area all products are visible, but in the webshop only products marked `active = 1` in the database table are visible.

I'm using Silex and register repositories as a service. How can I use the same repository/method to fetch products in both backend/frontend (and limit frontend to only active products) ?

I have thought of the following:

- Using a setter method to set a propery `backend = true` in the
  repository.
- Make two different repositories
- Extend the repository

Maybe I miss something but what is the correct and most beautiful way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

You could create a doctrine filter that (when enabled) will automatically add in the `active = true` to any SQL queries. You disable when accessing via the backend or when a user has a certain role (or doesn't, depending on your use case).

<kbd>Acme\ProductBundle\Doctrine\Filter\ActiveProductsFilter</kbd>

```
namespace Acme\ProductBundle\Doctrine\Filter;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetaData,
    Doctrine\ORM\Query\Filter\SQLFilter;

class ActiveProductsFilter extends SQLFilter
{

    public function addFilterConstraint(ClassMetadata $targetEntity, $targetTableAlias)
    {
        // Check if the entity implements the LocalAware interface
        if (!$targetEntity->reflClass
                ->implementsInterface('Acme\ProductBundle\Model\ProductInterface')) {
            return "";
        }

        return $targetTableAlias.'.active = '.$this->em->getConnection()
                                                            ->quote(true, 'boolean');
    }
}
```

<kbd>app/config/config.yml</kbd>

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        entity_managers:
            default:
                filters:
                    activeproducts:
                        class: Acme\ProductBundle\Doctrine\Filter\ActiveProductsFilter
                        enabled: true
```

Then you can use a listener or something to enable or disable depending on your requirements (current route, user role, etc) using

```
$em->getFilters()->disable('activeproducts');
```

Comment: The OP is using Silex so your solution does not directly apply to the case, but +1 for pointing the [filtering feature of Doctrine](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/filters.html).

Comment: My bad, I missed the `Silex` tag. I've never used Silex so as much as I want to see if I can make the answer fit the actual purpose I don't have the time.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest 2 different methods on the same repository, eg. `getProducts()` and `getActiveProducts()`, and call them appropriately. You could also make it a method arguments `getProducts($active = true)`

Comment: This is also a good idea :) Large number of method presents a challenge of maintaining the code but nevertheless it's a consistent way of doing things :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just pass `$backend` variable to a repository method?

It's a bit of a work always passing `TRUE` or `FALSE` to each method but this makes your code "more testable".

If that doesn't suit you, I would definitely go for your first suggestion, since you're already making your repositories as a service.